# How to add soap header to auto-generated proxies in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, header

So far I was doing proxies with *the manual way* and this is how I handled headers:

```
public abstract class UserClientBase<T> : ClientBase<T> where T : class
{
    public UserClientBase()
    {
        string userName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
        MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>(userName);

        OperationContextScope contextScope =
                        new OperationContextScope(InnerChannel);

        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                                  header.GetUntypedHeader("String", "System"));
    }
}

public class FooClient : UserClientBase<IFooService>, IFooService
{
    public Foo Test()
    {
        return Channel.Test();
    }
}
```

My question is.. **how can I do the that with auto-generated proxies??**, like this:

```
using (FooServiceClient client = new FooServiceClient())
{
    return await client.Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way as you did before. Almost.

```
Using Client As New FooServiceClient, Scope As New OperationContextScope(Client.InnerChannel)
    Dim Header As New MessageHeader(Of String)(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(Header.GetUntypedHeader("String", "System"))
    Return await client.Test();
End Using
```